# How to auto hide nav bar when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to build my first project, a restaurant website but having some trouble with toggling the nav bar. The nav bar links direct the user to the specified section, but the nav bar remains open after that section is reached/ How do I get it to close after clicking on a link?

This is the JavaScript I'm using:

```
        //select element function
        const selectElement=function(element){
        return document.querySelector(element);
        };

        let menuToggler=selectElement('.menu-toggle');
        let body=selectElement('body');

        menuToggler.addEventListener('click',function(){
        body.classList.toggle('open');
        });
```

the HTML of the header/navbar section :

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="nav" id="navbar">
          <div class="menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
          </div>
          <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="" alt=""></a>
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="index.html" class="nav-link present">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#menu" class="nav-link">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Order Online</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#Experience-Zen" class="nav-link">Make a Reservation</a>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Header ends-->
```

CSS of the header, using font awesome

```
.nav{
  height: 7.2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.menu-toggle{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 2.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1800;
}

/*to hide x of nav bar*/
.fa-times{
  display: none;
}

.nav-list{
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: var(--main-font-color-dark);
  padding: 4.4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  z-index: 1850;
  transform: translateX(-100%); /*hides nav bar*/
  transition: transform .5s;
}

/*before nav clicked*/
.nav::before{
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0;
  trasform:scale(0);
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.open .fa-times{
  display: block;
}
/*hides hamburger icon on clicking it*/
.open .fa-bars{
  display: none;
}

.open .nav-list{
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.open .nav::before{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: select the navbar element and set it display property to 'none'. ex: document.querySelector('elementname').style.display = "none".

Comment: So, the links in the menu are like: <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>? Maybe you can add some of your HTML to your question.

Comment: yes, after setting menu style property as display: none, the menu will get hide,

Answer (score 0):

```js
let navbar= document.getElementById("navbar")
let link= document.getElementById("link-a")
let showMenu= document.getElementById("show-menu")


 link.addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.display = "none"
        });

 showMenu.addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.display = "flex"
        });
```

```css
#navbar{
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background: red;

}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" >
<a id="link-a">Click me to hide menu</a>
</div>


<div id="show-menu"> Show menu</div>
```

small demo to toggle menu